# What is .zero in GNU gas?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

In the following compiler output:

```
a:
        .long   4
b:
        .byte   99
x:
        .zero   4
c:
        .byte   12
f:
        .zero   4
```

What does the `.zero` directive mean? It seems to be the only one not listed in the [`gas directives`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC137). Just from looking at the above, `long` is four bytes, `.byte` is one byte, and I'm guessing `.zero` means zero-for-four-bytes (or whatever the number is after the directive). Is that correct?

If so, why not just do `.long 0`. Does this put it in a different section or something?

Comment: A google search for `gas ".zero"` comes up with https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Zero.html (in the non-old manual) as the top hit: it's an alias for `.skip`.  And it's in the table of contents in the current manual.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/.  (Google for "gas manual" gives that as the top hit for me these days, but before google learned what I wanted I usually god there by searching for "gas manual" in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info because chrome's URL bar would auto-complete that easily for me by typing "x86/".)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it doesn't put it in a different section, it just puts it inline in whatever section you're currently creating.

In terms of its relationship to `.long`, the latter actually depends on the architecture. It could be a different size and/or endianness. Note the endianness probably won't matter for the zero value but the size may.

The `.zero` directive, on the other hand, is an alias for `.skip` (and `.space` on *some* architectures), and generates the requested number of bytes *regardless* of architecture.

Also keep in mind that, *as* an alias of `.skip`, you can also provide the *value* you want used for the bytes (it defaults to zero) but it makes little sense to do something like:

```
.zero 4, 32
```

to generate four spaces :-)

Comment: Theoretically, you could do a `.byte 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0` ... which is not very handy when replacing a `.zero 1000`.

Comment: The `.zero` might in fact *be* in a different section, because of directives that the Godbolt Compiler explorer hides by default. (not because of `.zero` itself; only `.common` and `.lcommon` reserve space in the BSS without switching to it). GCC and clang put zero-initialized static variables in `.bss`, otherwise `.data` or `.rodata`.  I think they only use `.zero` in the BSS.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: you could put `.byte 0` inside a `.rept` (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Rept.html)